# libpam-ldap or libpam-ldapd?

Tags: ubuntu, debian, authentication, ldap, pam

I'm setting up LDAP authentication on my personal VPS, and Ubuntu has two packages for the same purpose: [`libpam-ldap`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/natty/libpam-ldap) and [`libpam-ldapd`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/natty/libpam-ldapd). Which should I use?

Comment: For anyone seeing this thread in 2023, `libpam-ldap` has been removed from Debian 12 and replaced by `libpam-ldapd` due to lack of maintenance. See https://bugs.debian.org/1032123

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I am very fond of `libpam-ldapd`, have been using it for a year now in production on quite a few Ubuntu servers. I can recommend it over `libpam-ldap`.

The project is originally called `nss-pam-ldapd` and on [its homepage](http://arthurdejong.org/nss-pam-ldapd/) you can find a list of its biggest advantages over the old `libpam-ldap` package.

Edit: In conjunction with `libpam-ldapd` on Ubuntu you should also look into the `auth-client-config` package to correctly configure PAM et al.

Answer (score 7):

While `libnss-ldapd` is better than `libnss-ldap` in practically every way, the `libpam-ldapd` has one major deficiency: it can't handle LDAP `ppolicy`, and I couldn't find any information about password change using LDAP Extended Operation (it may handle it transparently).

If you have a "shadow" free LDAP (if you use `ppolicy` you most certainly will if you use OpenLDAP as both `ppolicy` and `smbk5pwd` don't update the shadow password ageing information) you need `libpam-ldap` or users won't be notified that their password will expire soon.

Thankfully, you can mix and match them. I've been using `libnss-ldapd` together with `libpam-ldap` for over a year now without any problems.

Answer (score 5):

One reason we have been forced to convert to `libpam-ldapd` is that we use SSL for our LDAP servers. Thanks to libgcrypt "brokenness" (see [Debian bug 566351](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=566351) or [Ubuntu bug 23252](https://bugs.launchpad.net/debian/+source/sudo/+bug/423252/comments/72), both entertaining), this means that `sudo` stops working when `libpam-ldap` & `libnss-ldap` are used with LDAP/SSL.

Your options if you want to use SSL with LDAP (and why wouldn't you?) are to recompile `libpam-ldap` with OpenSSL or use `libpam-ldapd`.

Comment: Wow, that's a pretty crazy thread. But it looks like they're dropping libgcrypt in favor of nettle?

Comment: Hasn't happened yet. Anyhow, lipam-ldapd is probably "better" from an architectural purity and security point of view, but if nslcd ever crashes you might be SOL.